# How to express "X sounds like Y"

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

How can I express the idea that one word sounds like another?

As a concrete example, I wanted to say, `「フライアー」sounds like 「fryer」`.

Looking in dictionaries ([wadoku](http://wadoku.de/search/klingen%20wie%C2%A0%E2%80%A6)/[jisho](http://beta.jisho.org/search/sound%20like)) for "sound like" turns up 「がましい」, but I could only find [one example sentence with that phrase on tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/170904), and it was used in a different way ("that sounds too forward").

Is there a better way to express what I want to say? Or, if がましい is actually correct, how exactly would I use this expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use

> XXはYYのように聞こえる
>   XXはYYみたいに聞こえる
>   XXはYYに聞こえる
>   XXはYYに(音が)似ている
>   XXはYYみたい(だ)
>   etc.

For example...

> 「Sit down please」は「しらんぷり」のように聞こえます。
>   「I get off」って、「揚げ豆腐」みたいに聞こえるね。(casual)
>   「フライアー」は、「fryer」に聞こえます。
>   「You know me」は、「湯飲み」に(音が)似ていますね。
>   「What time」って、「掘った芋」みたいだね。(casual)

---

がましい is used in set phrases like おこがましい、差し出がましい、未練がましい、押し付けがましい、言い訳がましい、恩着せがましい...

Comment: 「XXはYYのように聞こえる」と「XXはYYに聞こえる」は意味合いが違いますか？「XXはYYのように聞こえる」と「XXはYYみたいに聞こえる」は大体同じ意味合いだと思っていますが。

Comment: @Ataraxia 「XXはYYのように聞こえる」と言うと、「XXは、XXにも聞こえるし、YYにも聞こえる」という感じに使えますが、「XXはYYに聞こえる」と言うと、「XXは、XXでなく、(むしろ)YYに聞こえる」という感じに近くなると思います。