# How do you say "You sound like a ___?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, word-choice, expressions

I've been singing on a karaoke app recently and I wanted to comment on a person's voice. How would I go about saying "You sound like a rockstar!"

I was thinking 「Aさん、ロックスターみたいなぁ～」

Answer (score 4):

We have a post there [How to express “X sounds like Y”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17973/7810), which, however, not very useful for your case.

> Aさん、ロックスターみたいなぁ～

This is actually very very close, but no cigar. I'd say:

> Aさん、（まるで）ロックスターみたい（／みたいだ／みたいだなあ／みたいだね／みたいだよ）！

As you may know, it is most natural not to translate "sound" as is. Best using みたい whenever it is "sound" or "look" or "smell" or such.

But you can specify the origin of sensation, too. In this case, "sound" has no call either, because we would go one more step finer.

> Aさん、声がロックスターみたい！ (quality of voice)
> Aさん、歌い方がロックスターみたい！ (technique)
> Aさん、うますぎてロックスターみたい！ (good singer)
> etc.

Of course you can elongate the ending a bit, like how you put ～ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

How about this
あなたはロックスターのように聞こえます。
It seems pretty reasonable.